# the impact of sending large data using tcp protocol

Tags: tcp, network-programming, timeout

can someone explain why a TCP sender might automatically slow down when sending a large file? I understand that one reason could be the increased packet volume from the large data file, which would increase wait time and increase ACKS.

I was thinking that a second reason could be that the data caused a timeout, and following a timeout the cwnd is set to 1. If this second explanation is wrong could someone explain another reason for me?

Comment: Because the receiver will quench it when its receive buffer fills up.

Answer (score 0):

The high level answer is that there is a saturation effect.

The most likely low level cause of this would be that the receiver, via the TCP protocol, is indicating its Receive Queue (Recv-Q) is full. This typically happens when the Userspace application is not ingesting the data as fast as it is being sent. This causes a traffic jam on the sender's Send Queue (Send-Q) as well. Both of these queues/buffers are in the operating system and can be examined with `netstat` or the more modern `ss` commands. The more exact `ss` command would look like: `ss -tn state established`.

That being said other saturation effects are possible. If there is a throughput bottleneck somewhere, and you could be contesting with other application for throughput. The longer you hog the channel the higher the chance of contention. This would likely show in a high Send-Q but a low Recv-Q.